# How to bind @html.ajaxgrid with ajax call and once grid is loaded so I want to alert("Loaded") in ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am loading ajax grid. everything is working fine but I want to use this with ajax call instead so whenever grid load is success i want to alert a message liked loaded sucessfully.

My current code:

```
 <div id="userList">
                    @Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("GetRoleRequestReport", "Report", new { ReportType = "StateRoleRequestReport" }))
                </div>
```

But I am planning to use something like this and bind the result to div

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRoleRequestReport", "Report")',
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {
                   alert("loaded successfully");
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
```

I tried something like this but does not work

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRoleRequestReport", "Report", new { ReportType = "LocalRoleRequestReport" })',
                type: "GET",
                success: function (response) {
                  $('#userList').html(@Html.AjaxGrid(response.data));
                    alert("Hello Loaded");
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: `@Html.AjaxGrid()` is server side code as is executed on the server before the page is sent to the client - your `response.data` does not exist at that point (and what is `@Html.AjaxGrid()` - that is not part of the mvc framework - a link to the plugin would help)

Comment: Are you having `$('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid()` somewhere in JS? If it's true, you may trying `reloadEnded` event: `$('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid({ requestType: 'get', query: '@Url.Action("GetRoleRequestReport", "Report", new { ReportType = "LocalRoleRequestReport" })', reloadEnded: function() { alert("Hello Loaded"); } });`